# Killing all process from command line

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

I would like to killing all the firefox processes from command line.

### For example:

```
MacPro:huangr$ ps -x | grep 'firefox'
 4147 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4177 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4234 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4273 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4282 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4285 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4298 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4301 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4304 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4311 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4317 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4320 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4338 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4342 ttys000    0:00.00 (firefox-bin)
 4377 ttys000    0:03.85 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
 4394 ttys000    0:05.54 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
 4471 ttys000    0:06.08 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
 4581 ttys002    0:04.92 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
 4607 ttys002    0:04.33 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
 4626 ttys002    0:05.04 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -no-remote -foreground
```

I would like to kill all of them in one shot, any easy way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Not really a programming question, try at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9):

```
kill -9 $(ps -x | grep 'firefox' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Should do it

Comment: This does not work for OS X 10.8.5. It results in an error `kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly.

```
ps -ef | grep '[f]irefox' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 ;
```

or

```
ps -ef | awk '/[f]irefox/ {print $1}' | xargs kill -9 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note -

kill -9 is overkill (no pun intended) because it prevents the killed process from running cleanup (e.g., atexit() calls, like the difference between exit and _exit).  It may or may not be a problem with firefox, but in general consider trying  "kill -9" only after plain "kill" fails.

Answer (score 0):

`killall firefox-bin`

or

`killall -9 firefox-bin`

if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -

```
kill `awk '$4~/firefox/{print $1}' <(ps -x)`
```

Or on a generic note, add this function to your startup script -

```
killp() {
awk -v pname="$1" '$4~/pname/{print $1}' <(ps -e) | xargs kill
}
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sleep 100&
[1] 52530
[jaypal:~/Temp] sleep 100&
[2] 52531
[jaypal:~/Temp] killp sleep
[1]-  Terminated: 15          sleep 100
[2]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 100
```